# ¿Como agregar restricciones a objeto de tipo "Criteria" cuando el atributo de criterio es de una clase externa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Tengo el siguiente dilema para generar una lista de todas las credenciales que pertenezcan un hostFisico especifico.

Clase **FisicHost**

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class FisicHost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Datacenter datacenter;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fisicHost")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Credential> credentials;

    private String name;
    private String ip;
    private String operatingSystem;
    private String notes;

    public FisicHost(){

    }

    public FisicHost(Long id, Datacenter datacenter, List<Credential> credentials, String name, String ip, String operatingSystem, String notes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.datacenter = datacenter;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.name = name;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Datacenter getDatacenter() {
        return datacenter;
    }

    public void setDatacenter(Datacenter datacenter) {
        this.datacenter = datacenter;
    }

    public List<Credential> getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    public void setCredentials(List<Credential> credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public String getOperatingSystem() {
        return operatingSystem;
    }

    public void setOperatingSystem(String operatingSystem) {
        this.operatingSystem = operatingSystem;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```

Clase **Credential**

```
@Entity
public class Credential {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private FisicHost fisicHost;

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String notes;
    private String role;

    public Credential(){

    }

    public Credential(int id, FisicHost fisicHost, String user, String password, String notes, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fisicHost = fisicHost;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FisicHost getFisicHost() {
        return fisicHost;
    }

    public void setFisicHost(FisicHost fisicHost) {
        this.fisicHost = fisicHost;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Y en este método del Repositorio estoy intentando hacerlo así, pero me parece que acá está el error:

```
@Repository
public class CredentialDaoImpl implements CredentialDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Credential> getAllCredentialsByFisicHost(FisicHost fisicHost) {
        // Open a session
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Credential.class).add(Restrictions.eq("fisicHost", fisicHost.getId()));

        List<Credential> allCredentials = c.list();

        // Close the session
        session.close();

        return allCredentials;
    }
```

Y la llamada desde el controlador se produce así:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chosenDatacenter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String datacenterPostHandler(@RequestParam("datacenterList") String name, ModelMap modelMap){
    List<Datacenter> allDatacenters = datacenterDao.getAllDatacenters();
    for (Datacenter dc : allDatacenters) {
        if (dc.getName().equals(name)) {
        modelMap.put("datacenter", dc);
        if(dc.getFisicHostList().size() != 0) {
            List<FisicHost> datacenterFisicHosts = dc.getFisicHostList();
            modelMap.put("datacenterFisicHosts", datacenterFisicHosts);
            for(FisicHost fh : datacenterFisicHosts){
                if(fh.getCredentials().size() != 0){
                    modelMap.put("fisicHostCredentialsList", credentialDao.getAllCredentialsByFisicHost(fh));
                }
            }
        }
        return "chosenDatacenter";
        }
    }
        return null;
}
```

y me tira este error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long
>   com.amco.Datacenter.model.FisicHost.id] by reflection for persistent
>   property [com.amco.Datacenter.model.FisicHost#id] : 20; nested
>   exception is
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.Long
>   com.amco.Datacenter.model.FisicHost.id] by reflection for persistent
>   property [com.amco.Datacenter.model.FisicHost#id] : 20

Estoy seguro de que el problema está en esta línea de la clase CredentialDaoImpl

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Credential.class).add(Restrictions.eq("fisicHost", fisicHost.getId()));
```

ya que el ID#20 en mi base de datos corresponde con un FisicHost que es el que uso para testear, pero no sé como solucionar el problema.

¿Como puedo hacer que el criterio de busqueda sea por ID cuando el ID que estoy buscando es de un objeto de otra clase?

Basicamente estoy haciendo todo esto para obtener las credenciales dentro de cada FisicHost y desplegarlas en el template correspondiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando esta línea (la diferencia está en hacer referencia al atributo id de fisicHost):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Credential.class).add(Restrictions.eq("fisicHost.id", fisicHost.getId()));
```